# JavaScript conditions for checkbox OnLoad

Tags: javascript, checkbox, conditional-statements, onload

I have a checkbox which determines whether to hide or make elements visible. My question: is there a way to also include if the checkbox was originally unchecked on page-load to permanently remove those elements so they can't be recalled, otherwise continue what is currently below? Hope that makes sense.

```
function myEmail() {
    var emailBox = document.getElementById("checkemail");
    var emailradios = document.getElementById("emailradios");
    var emailOptOutSix = document.getElementById("emailOptOutSix");
    var emailOptOutForever = document.getElementById("emailOptOutForever");

    if (emailBox.checked == true){
        emailradios.style.visibility = "hidden";
        emailforever.style.visibility = "hidden";
        emailOptOutSix.checked = false;
        emailOptOutForever.checked = false;

    } else {
       emailradios.style.visibility = "visible";
       emailforever.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a little unclear what your asking. If you want to delete the items when  the checkbox is unchecked (on page load) then you could do this:

Here is a working version [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bsalines/ev6d5sk3/30/)

It should be noted, that getting the cookie using substring is not the best practice. It would be wise to create a function that handles this. An example can be found here. [Working with cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

```
//gets the cookie for checked/not checked state
var checked = document.cookie;

//On window load
window.onload = function() {
  //Get the value of the cookie
  var emailBoxChecked = checked.substring(checked.indexOf("=") + 1);
  if (emailBoxChecked == "checked"){
      //set the state of the checkbox to true
      document.getElementById("emailbox").checked = true
      //If checked do something

  } else {
      //set the state of the checkbox to false
      document.getElementById("emailbox").checked = false
      //remove radio buttons that are contained within the emailRadios div
      var parent = document.getElementById("myForm")
      var child = document.getElementById("emailRadios")
      parent.removeChild(child)


  }
};


//Call this function when the checkbox is clicked
var emailChecked = function () { 
   var emailBoxChecked = document.getElementById("emailbox").checked
   if (emailBoxChecked){
      // store the state of the checkbox as checked in a cookie
      document.cookie = "email=checked";
   } else {
      // store the state of the checkbox as NOT checked in a cookie
      document.cookie = "email=unchecked";
   }
}
```

Comment: np. Never easy explaining it in text. So the scripts I have above basically is functionality for a checkbox which showes and hides a couple of radio buttons when checked. That's great.

The extra functionality would be; when the page loads, if the check box is unchecked (), how can the elements for 'emailradios' & 'emailforever' be permanantly removed so they do not show at all when the checkbox is checked or not checked. But ofcourse if the page loads with the checkbox ticked, the functionality works?

Comment: This would really depend on where your calling myEmail(). Once those elements are deleted, you will get an error if you try to call that function.

Comment: So I'm calling the myEmail after the HTML. I tried putting in thewindow.onload in after my script. The checkbox isn't checked and the elements have not been remove :( I can tell this when I check then uncheck the box the elements appear. Any ideas?

Comment: I wrote up a quick example (see JSFiddle link above) of removing some radio buttons (on page load)  if the checkbox is checked. In order to know if the checkbox was checked on a previous visit to your site you need to store that information somewhere. In my example I stored it using cookies since it was the fastest way to write the example.